# How to sync two range slider present on different pages in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, echarts, rangeslider

I have 2 range sliders on my website. Both of them lie at different sections of the same page.

1. One Range slider is from apache echarts. This controls my candle stick chart.
   https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=custom-ohlc
2. Second range slider is from below and this controls my map from leaflet.js
   https://github.com/slawomir-zaziablo/range-slider

Both the range sliders have the same values on their scale.

I want to link these two range sliders such that when one is moved the other one also moves and gets set to the same value and vice-versa. Basically, I want to sync these two range sliders.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: I don't know much about echarts and range sliders but this looks like something that shared state can fix. You need to share state between these two sliders.

Comment: Additionally: Figure out for both sliders: 1. How to detect if they are changed (callback, onchange etc.), 2. How to set their value via JS. Then you add for each slider something like onchange -> changeOther()